# Como formatar links específicos?

Tags: html, css

A maneira que eu aprendi, é que eu aplico o estilo em todos os links, queria saber como eu poderia fazer isso, aqui tem  duas divs eu queria aplicar os estilos apenas na primeira div com o id="links1"

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo listas</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        a{
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:link, a:visited{
            color: blue;
        }

        a:hover{
            color: white;
            background: yellow;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="links1">
        <a href="">Google</a>
        <a href="">You Tube</a>
        <a href="">Facebook</a>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <br>
    <div id="links2">
        <a href="">Google</a>
        <a href="">You Tube</a>
        <a href="">Facebook</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode aplicar o estilo à classes, tags ou id's. Para aplicar às classes, basta adicionar a classe à sua tag com o atributo `class="nome_da_classe"`. Dessa maneira, o CSS fica assim:

```
.nome_da_classe{
  atributo1: 10px;
  atributo2: 10px;
  ...
}
```

Da mesma maneira, você faz com os id's, porém repare que uso `#` em vez de `.` pra indicar que estou aplicando um CSS a um ID específico e não uma classe. Você define através do atributo `id` nas tags e seu CSS fica dessa maneira:

```
#id{
  atributo1: 10px;
  atributo2: 10px;
  ...
}
```

Importante entender que você usa classes quando quer estender um determinado estilo a vários componentes e não quer escrever um CSS para cada um deles. Você usa o estilo para um ID quando quer um componente específico com aquele CSS que você codificou. E finalmente, as tags recebem estilo de maneira geral quando normalmente você não irá alterá-las dentro de classes e ids (exemplo: toda tag `<p>` deve ter uma fonte `Arial`; dessa forma, toda tag `p`, desde que não tenha seu CSS sobrescrito, terá essa fonte).

Comment: Entendi, não sabia que dava para fazer isso, obrigado